# Which sensor to use to detect physical phone rotation?

Tags: android

I am new to android programming, but I'm trying to create an app which measures if a person squats below parallel.
My idea to do this was that the person would keep his phone vertically in his pocket and when he squats the phone would be horizontal.

In order to detect if the squat was below parallel the rotation would need to be over 90°.

I've tried using the orientation sensor and the gyroscope, but the data i get doesn't seem accurate at all. Maybe I'm using wrong.

Does anyone know what sensor I would use for this? Or maybe a whole different idea to do this?

Comment: *the person would keep his phone vertically in his pocket and when he squats the phone would be horizontal.* that is a dangerous assumption to make, likely to fail in real life scenarios

Comment: Gyroscope: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228586/android-studio-gyroscope-examples

Answer (score 0):

I think using the accelerometer is a better option.

```
private SensorManager sensorManager;  
private Sensor accelerometer;
sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);  
accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);
```

Once you have collected some data, you must analyse it and find the squat pattern. It may be something like: no acceleration, acceleration downwards, no acceleration, acceleration upwards. Then you have to build your app in order to recognise this pattern and count +1 every time the pattern repeats.

Comment: It would be more complex than that because the phone's orientation would change during motion making simplistic determination more complex.

Comment: I agree with you, Android sensors data are relative to a device. But you can always transform any vector from the phone's coordinate system to the Earth's coordinate system.